# Indesign - How to create a conditional space between fields in a data merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

When performing a data merge in InDesign, is there a way to conditionally include a space between fields? Something like as follows:

`<<Title>>[conditional space here]<<Name>>`

Not all records have a `<<Title>>` and `Remove blank lines for empty fields` is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use a GREP style to make this "conditional space" visible or not. Please note this workaround would work assuming your paragraph starts with "Title" or "Name", otherwise we shall think differently...

1- Insert a normal space between your fields:

```
<<Title>>[normal space]<<Name>>
```

2- Create a character style (let's call it "invisible"). Set Font size to minimum (0.1pt) and approach to -1000.

3- Open your paragraph style settings, go to GREP style and apply this "invisible" character style to a space at the beginning of the paragraph. Use Grep regex: **^\s**. This way, if there is no "Title", you'll have [invisible space] + "Name".

[image]

Comment: Nice trick. FWIW Colin Flashman many other great datamerge techniques at https://colecandoo.com/. But at some point it's better to start on working with professionnal plugins that will bring hogher levels of productivity and smoothness.

Comment: Merci pour le lien @Loic.

Comment: My pleasure @Vinny

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. The data merge functionality in InDesign is quite limited – although good enough in most cases. An Xmpie plugin could do it, but that might be an expensive solution if the project isn't very big.

What may work is doing the data merge into a new ID file instead of exporting directly to PDF, and then do a find and replace on for instance on beginning whitespace.